# Use rs485 driver specifying the DE pin

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, embedded, serial-port, uart

On an embedded system (STM32MP1 w/ Yocto environment) I need to control an rs485 transceiver.
Unfortunately, the `DE` pin of the transceiver is connected to a generic GPIO pin of the MPU and not to the built-in `DE/RTS` alternate function pin.

That means I need to manually control that pin during transmissions. Of course it's not so easy especially when the remote device answers very fast!

I read some resources about how to use rs485 in Linux, i.e.:

https://www.acmesystems.it/28

https://armbedded.taskit.de/node/322

but I don't understand how to specify which pin should be assigned to the `DE` function.
I also checked the kernel source code here:

https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/include_2uapi_2linux_2serial_8h_source.html

but still the `struct serial_rs485` seems to lack the definition of the `DE` pin.
Perhaps they want to use the `RTS` signal, but as said I cannot use it. I need to select a specific GPIO.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the RS485 transceiver? Because that's the piece of hardware the kernel is actually talking to.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, it's a common `SN65HVD178` transceiver, nothing special. The `DE` and `~RE` pins are connected together to a generic GPIO pin of the MPU (without any related alternate function).